# Tool to measure Render time

Tags: html, performance, browser, rendering

Is there a tool out there to measure the actual Render time of an element(s) on a page?  I don't mean download time of the resources, but the actual time the browser took to render something.  I know that this time would vary based on factors on the client machine, but would still be very handy in knowing what the rendering engine takes a while to load.  I would imagine this should be a useful utility since web apps are becoming pretty client heavy now.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using this script to analyze rendering time of some pages:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<?

    $output = str_replace('=', 'A', base64_encode(file_get_contents('data.txt')));

    echo "\tCode = \"" . substr($output, 0, 512) . "\"";
    $size = strlen($output);
    for ($i = 512; $i < $size; $i += 512)
        echo "\n\t     + \"" . substr($output, $i, 512) . "\"";
    echo ";\n";

?>
    Data = "";
    Dict = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

    j = Code.length -3;
    for (i = 0; i < j; i += 4) {
        Data += String.fromCharCode(((Dict.indexOf(Code.charAt(i    )) << 2) | (Dict.indexOf(Code.charAt(i + 1)) >> 4)) & 0xff);
        Data += String.fromCharCode(((Dict.indexOf(Code.charAt(i + 1)) << 4) | (Dict.indexOf(Code.charAt(i + 2)) >> 2)) & 0xff);
        Data += String.fromCharCode(((Dict.indexOf(Code.charAt(i + 2)) << 6) | (Dict.indexOf(Code.charAt(i + 3))     )) & 0xff);
    }

    time_start = (new Date).valueOf()/1000;
    document.write(Data);
    time_elapsed = (new Date).valueOf()/1000 - time_start;

    alert(time_elapsed);

</script>
```

Part PHP, part JavaScript. **data.txt** is the file containing the HTML to analyze.
Tested on IE and FF.

Comment: PS: It won't consider time needed to load linked resources, like external .CSS files or images, unless you're using mod_expire at them. Maybe you want to hook the document.body.onload too, but then the result will also vary by your connection speed and latency.

Answer (score 3):

You can check out [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/).

Edit: It seems to me that [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) shows the rendering time with a blue and red line in the net panel.

Comment: I looked at YSlow.  It gives you an overall view of performance, load times, and cache stats, but nothing on how long a specific element took to render as far as I saw.  Am i missing something?

Comment: It only makes suggestions on some DOM elements to be removed. I believe actual rendering times pretty much depend on the browser.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest YSlow.

It not only measures performance times of the elements in your page but it also analyzes your page design to suggest how you can make performance improvements. **It is one of the tools they used in the development of Stack Overflow.**

[Yahoo! YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/)

> YSlow analyzes web pages and suggests
>   ways to improve their performance
>   based on a set of rules for high
>   performance web pages. YSlow is a
>   Firefox add-on integrated with the
>   Firebug web development tool. YSlow
>   grades web page based on one of three
>   predefined ruleset or a user-defined
>   ruleset. It offers suggestions for
>   improving the page's performance,
>   summarizes the page's components,
>   displays statistics about the page,
>   and provides tools for performance
>   analysis, including Smush.it™ and
>   JSLint.

Comment: How can I see the performance times of the elements on the page with YSlow?  I tried looking for it, can't find it...

Answer (score 1):

Firebug for Firefox has it integrated in the "Net"-Tab.

Needs Firefox (I did it with version 12.0) configuration modified, type `about:config` in address bar and then search for `dom.send_after_paint_to_content`

Set `dom.send_after_paint_to_content` to true.

`MozAfterPaint` is then painted as small green vertical lines in the network loading timeline in addition to the blue (`DOMContentLoaded`) and red (load) lines.

Comment: i've set dom.send_after_paint_to_content = true in FF 19.0.2 but don't get any green line....?!