# Can anyone give a list of REST APIs to query elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

1. I am trying to push my logs to elasticsearch through logstash.
2. My `logstash.conf` have 2 log files as input; elasticsearch as output; and grok as filter. Here is my grok match:

   ```
   grok {
     match => [ "message", "(?<timestamp>[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}
   [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}) 
   (?:\[%{GREEDYDATA:caller_thread}\]) (?:%{LOGLEVEL:level}) 
   (?:%{DATA:caller_class})(?:\-%{GREEDYDATA:message})" ]
      }
   ```
3. When elasticsearch is started, all my logs are added to elasticsearch server with seperate index name as mentioned in `logstash.conf`.
4. My doubt is that how my logs are stored in elasticsearch? I only know that it is stored with the index name as mentioned in logstash.

'http://164.99.178.18:9200/_cat/indices?v'  API given me the following:

health status index         pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size

```
yellow open   tomcat-log      5   1       6478            0      1.9mb          1.9mb 

yellow open   apache-log      5   1        212            0      137kb   
   137kb
```

5. But, how 'documents', 'fields' are created in elasticsearch for my logs.

I read that elasticsearch is REST based search engine. So, if there any REST APIs that I could use to analyze my data in elasticsearch.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323449/tool-to-measure-render-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed.

```
curl localhost:9200/tomcat-log/_search
```

Will give you back the first 10 documents but also the total number of docs in your index.

```
curl localhost:9200/tomcat-log/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "level" : "error"
    }
  }
}'
```

might gives you all docs in tomcat-log which have level equal to error.

Have a look at this section of the [book](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/search.html). It will help.

Comment: Yes and I would add curl localhost:9200/tomcat-log/_mapping to the toolbox as well, would give the mapping for all the fields in your index.